# highchart Customclass css not applied to tooltip for dumbbell series

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular-highcharts

i'm working on dumbbell series highchart

i'm using custom class for charts which is working fine.

but it's not applied in the highchart tooltip and legand.
I used the same class for other charts where it's working fine. it isn't working in the dumbbell series
[image]
i searched lot to find this issue but i couldn't find any solution.

here you can find my code

```
{
  chart: {
    type: 'dumbbell',
    inverted: true,
    className: Classes.HIGHCHARTS_THEME,
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false,
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: '1960 vs 2018',
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Change in Life Expectancy',
  },

  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Life Expectancy (years)',
    },
  },

  series: [
    {
      type: 'dumbbell',
      name: 'Life expectancy change',
      data: [
        {
          name: 'Austria',
          low: 69,
          high: 82,
        },
        {
          name: 'Belgium',
          low: 70,
          high: 81,
        },
        {
          name: 'Bulgaria',
          low: 69,
          high: 75,
        },
        {
          name: 'Croatia',
          low: 65,
          high: 78,
        },
        {
          name: 'Cyprus',
          low: 70,
          high: 81,
        },
        {
          name: 'Czech Republic',
          low: 70,
          high: 79,
        },
        {
          name: 'Denmark',
          low: 72,
          high: 81,
        },
        {
          name: 'Estonia',
          low: 68,
          high: 78,
        },
        {
          name: 'Finland',
          low: 69,
          high: 81,
        },
        {
          name: 'France',
          low: 70,
          high: 83,
        },
        {
          name: 'Greece',
          low: 68,
          high: 81,
        },
        {
          name: 'Spain',
          low: 69,
          high: 83,
        },
        {
          name: 'Netherlands',
          low: 73,
          high: 82,
        },
        {
          name: 'Ireland',
          low: 70,
          high: 82,
        },
        {
          name: 'Lithuania',
          low: 70,
          high: 75,
        },
        {
          name: 'Luxembourg',
          low: 68,
          high: 83,
        },
        {
          name: 'Latvia',
          low: 70,
          high: 75,
        },
        {
          name: 'Malta',
          low: 69,
          high: 82,
        },
        {
          name: 'Germany',
          low: 69,
          high: 81,
        },
        {
          name: 'Poland',
          low: 68,
          high: 78,
        },
        {
          name: 'Portugal',
          low: 63,
          high: 81,
        },
        {
          name: 'Romania',
          low: 66,
          high: 75,
        },
        {
          name: 'Slovakia',
          low: 70,
          high: 77,
        },
        {
          name: 'Slovenia',
          low: 69,
          high: 81,
        },
        {
          name: 'Sweden',
          low: 73,
          high: 82,
        },
        {
          name: 'Hungary',
          low: 68,
          high: 76,
        },
        {
          name: 'Italy',
          low: 69,
          high: 83,
        },
        {
          name: 'UK',
          low: 71,
          high: 81,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
  },
}
```

can anyone tell me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you nedd to add the custom `className` to the `tooltip` options.

```
  tooltip: {
    className: 'myClass'
  },
```

Then `.myClass` is set for a group of tooltips. For the one tooltip is created `.myClass-box` class, which has a higher priority and where you should apply CSS rules.

```
.myClass, .myClass-box {
  fill: red;
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8hj3rtqk/